# libGDX - Using a HashMap causes growing HeapSize and Out of Memory on Android Phone

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, hashmap, libgdx

I'm facing a problem with a fast growing heap size because of using a HashMap. All works fine in the Desktop version but crashes on Android with the following Error:

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(23022): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.307MB for 767952-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(23022): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.486MB for 767952-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(23022): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.661MB for 767952-byte allocation
W/Adreno200-GSL(23022): <gsl_ldd_control:230>: ioctl fd 52 code 0xc00c092f    (IOCTL_KGSL_GPMEM_ALLOC) failed: errno 12 Out of memory,inBufSizeBytes:12,inBuf:0x539f185c
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class SkillManager {

    // all skills in one map
    private Map<Class, AbstractBaseSkill> skills;

    // singleton
    private static SkillManager instance;

    public static SkillManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SkillManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SkillManager() {
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "#SkillManager Cstr");

        skills = new HashMap<Class, AbstractBaseSkill>();
        skills.put(Skill1.class, Skill1.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill2.class, Skill2.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill3.class, Skill3.getInstance()); // crash on android
        skills.put(Skill4.class, Skill4.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill5.class, Skill5.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill6.class, Skill6.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill7.class, Skill7.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill8.class, Skill8.getInstance());

        skills.put(Skill9.class, Skill9.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill10.class, Skill10.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill11.class, Skill11.getInstance());
        skills.put(Skill12.class, Skill12.getInstance());
    }
```

The SkillManager constructor only gets called one time after loading the MainMenuScreen. So what is the problem with that? There are not that much entries? All the singletons I put in have an empty constructor. The first two entries are working fine, but at the third entry the heap size gets too big. Is it because of the singletons or because using a HashMap with that types is not recommended? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm not that experienced yet...

Thx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using SoftReferences or WeakReferences helps.

Also there is this good article on avoiding out of memory 
http://blogs.innovationm.com/android-out-of-memory-error-causes-solution-and-best-practices/

A temporary hack(Solve the issue before you publish the build) for this is increasing the heap size in manifest
android:largeHeap="true"